# How to prepare an OCSP request in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, openssl, ocsp

I am preparing a **iOS** application which needs to create an OCSP request and sent it to CA server to check the status of a certificate.

I have integrated **OpenSSL** library to my **x-code project**.
There is one header file named **ocsp.h** in OpenSSL which defines the ocsp request and response structures.

Can anyone help me to find any resource or way to make a request and parse the response of OCSP?

Comment: *"Can anyone help me to find any resource or way to make a request..."* - There's a lot to it. Examine the source code for the `ocsp` subcommand. You can find it at [`<openssl dir>/apps/ocsp.c`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/ocsp.c)

Comment: @jww Thanks a lot for your help.
I have prepared an objective-c file to get the status of a certificate.